# Escaping Preg_match in php 7.3

Tags: php, regex, php-7.3

Updated php of my application to 7.3 but now most of the preg_match are showing: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 23.

I did read that it is a escape problem but somehow i can't get it right.

URL to the regex https://regex101.com/r/JCSyJp/2/

Trying to escape - and \ chars but nothing is working.

Some one please help me out.

Comment: Put the hyphen at the beginning or at the end of character class.

Comment: Thanks, working fine!

Comment: Fine, I'll make this comment an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764212/preg-match-compilation-failed-invalid-range-in-character-class-at-offset)

Answer (score 1):

Put the hyphen at the beginning or at the end of character class:

```
(?:^(?<host>[\w-]+\.[\w.-]*?)\.\s*(?<ttl>\d+)\s*(?<wtf>\w*)\s*(?<rectype>\w*)\s*(?<value>.*)\s*$)
```