# I have an Error in Direct Print to thermal page printing program

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 29 in E:\xampp\htdocs\2019\FOLDER\test\ImpresionTermica\ImpresionTermica\ticket\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 126

Print Command is getting to printer but browser it shows like this and in printer queue it shows error.

Comment: It'd be bit helpful if you shared your regex pattern. Maybe take a look at, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24767090/3857918

Comment: i shared  take a look