# Why does PHP Simple DOM library not work with PHP 7.4.5?

Tags: php, regex

Does anyone have idea that why the `Simple PHP Dom library` is not working with `PHP 7.4.5` version? Even not working with `7.1.x` version too.

I'll be thankful If anyone share his/her thoughts on it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that library is written for PHP 4/5.6x. https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-html/ :( Any workaround to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like I found the answer but not the solution yet! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764212/preg-match-compilation-failed-invalid-range-in-character-class-at-offset

Since the PCRE2 is more strict iin PHP 7.x and I believe this is the reason it's not working and expression will need to be modified.