# How do I convert PHP 5 regular expression to PHP 7 standards?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I was using the `PHP Simple Dom library` which was working perfectly in `PHP 5.6.x`. Now, we are migrating our system from this version to `PHP 7.4.5` and unfortunately this library has badly paused us.

After hours of troubleshooting, I did figured this out that this expression is causing the reason. This is old standard `PHP 5 based regular expression` which needs to be `converted into the PHP 7.x`.

```
/([\w-:\*]*)(?:\#([\w-]+)|\.([\w-]+))?(?:\[@?(!?[\w-:]+)(?:([!*^$]?=)["']?(.*?)["']?)?\])?([\/, ]+)/is
```

Can anyone please help on it?

Just got stuck in big hell of issue. Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: How was that being used? What errors do you receive, what strings are going into it? I don't follow how a regex and a parser work together. I don't use simple dom though, https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php.

Comment: This library is used to parse the Html pages. So the expression mentioned in above description is basically based on the old PCRE standards which isn't working in PHP 7.x because PHP 7.x works with PCRE2 which is more strict in validating the patterns. - That's the problem. 

I think I found the solution here but not tested yet!
https://php.watch/versions/7.3/pcre2

Comment: Oh, you should add the information to the question. The `-` should never be in the middle of a character class unless it is making a range. It should be first or last otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand this. I have made so much attempts but got no success. It has waste so much hours and haven't made any progress. Can you please help me sending the correct one?

Comment: Well, you *are* there, my answer is the solution. Move `-` to the end of the 2 character classes, `[\w-:]` => `[\w:-]` and `[\w-:\*]` => `[\w:*-]`. Use `/([\w:*-]*)(?:#([\w-]+)|\.([\w-]+))?(?:\[@?(!?[\w:-]+)(?:([!*^$]?=)["']?(.*?)["']?)?])?([\/, ]+)/`  - no `is` at the end needed. Although I have no idea why you have `(!?[\w:-]+)`, it looks very suspicious.

Comment: Tried but still not getting the results. But I appreciate for helping me on it. - Thanks