# which ways may I try to solve this annoying error of visual composer?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I'm making pages using drag and drop with **wpbakery page builder** in **wordpress**.
so I'm designing my blog page and when I want to try some **grid elements** this error shows up.
`Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 12 in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-content\plugins\js_composer\include\classes\shortcodes\vc-basic-grid.php on line 184`

the code it's warning is `$content = $found[6][ $key ];`
I will attach the whole file to [this link](https://mega.nz/file/Gzx0zQLA#sTIzWyFhTtrUq48Y5qbu4UvhljLQixoJaUnFNBAQ_kw) so you can download and see this `php` file

now I'm working on localhost,my theme is Mediacenter and my page builder is Visual Composer v5.6 and wordpress is up to date.

I found out that it may cause by php version but maybe I can somehow edit my code.I just want to know where is wrong in code

Comment: please refer this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764212/preg-match-compilation-failed-invalid-range-in-character-class-at-offset

Comment: @Bhautik thank you and I must say I already read it but in that case problem isn't in visual composer plugin so I taught maybe there's an easier way to explain it...