# RegEx failing since PHP 7.4, working in 7.3

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Any ideas why this preg_match works up to PHP7.2 but fails with 7.3+ ?

```
$word = 'umweltfreundilch'; //real life example :/
preg_match('/^(?U)(.*(?:[aeiouyäöü])(?:[^aeiouyäöü]))(?X)(.*)$/u', $word, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (? or (?-

PHP 7.2 and below output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "umweltfreundilch"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "um"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "weltfreundilch"
}
```

RegEx seems to be ok, doesn't it?
https://regex101.com/r/LGdhaM/1

Comment: Does it work without the `äöü` in the regex?

Comment: no, same error. sry should've mentioned that... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP 7.3 and later, the Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) extension [was upgraded](https://www.icdsoft.com/blog/whats-new-in-php-7-3/) to PCRE2.

The [PCRE2 syntax documentation](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html) does not list `(?X)` as an available inline modifier option. Here are the supported options:

```
  (?i)            caseless
  (?J)            allow duplicate named groups
  (?m)            multiline
  (?n)            no auto capture
  (?s)            single line (dotall)
  (?U)            default ungreedy (lazy)
  (?x)            extended: ignore white space except in classes
  (?xx)           as (?x) but also ignore space and tab in classes
  (?-...)         unset option(s)
  (?^)            unset imnsx options
```

However, you may actually use `X` flag after the trailing delimiter:

```
preg_match('/^(?U)(.*[aeiouyäöü][^aeiouyäöü])(.*)$/Xu', $word, $matches)
```

See [PHP 7.4 demo](https://3v4l.org/vEvuc).

To cancel `(?U)` effect, you may use either of the two options: a `(?-U)` inline modifier, like in

```
preg_match('/^(?U)(.*[aeiouyäöü][^aeiouyäöü])(?-U)(.*)$/u', $word, $matches);
//                                           ^^^^^
```

Or, enclose the affected patterns into a `(?U:...)` modifier group:

```
preg_match('/^(?U:(.*[aeiouyäöü][^aeiouyäöü]))(.*)$/u', $word, $matches);
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See more about changes to regex handling in PHP 7.3+ in [preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551371/3832970).