# PHP7.4 : preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unrecognised compile-time option bit(s) at offset 0

Tags: php

We are using ubuntu 20.04, PHP7.4, and Azure SQL

Message: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unrecognised compile-time option bit(s) at offset 0

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 725

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/api/index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once

This is the code from Filename: core/Common.php

```
function remove_invisible_characters($str, $url_encoded = TRUE)
    {
        $non_displayables = array();

        // every control character except newline (dec 10),
        // carriage return (dec 13) and horizontal tab (dec 09)
        if ($url_encoded)
        {
            $non_displayables[] = '/%0[0-8bcef]/i'; // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
            $non_displayables[] = '/%1[0-9a-f]/i';  // url encoded 16-31
            $non_displayables[] = '/%7f/i'; // url encoded 127
        }

        $non_displayables[] = '/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+/S';   // 00-08, 11, 12, 14-31, 127

        do
        {
            $str = preg_replace($non_displayables, '', $str, -1, $count);
        }
        while ($count);

        return $str;
    }
}
```

Code from: File: /var/www/html/api/index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx failing since PHP 7.4, working in 7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826129/regex-failing-since-php-7-4-working-in-7-3)

Comment: I had the same problem after installing PHP 8.0.13, fixed by upgrading packages afterward with sudo apt upgrade

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem, and I found this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81640

By updating libpcre2-8-0 from version 10.36 to 10.39 it seems to correct the problem. I will try this step

> Never put on production one evening on the full moon ^^

Comment: I confirm !

> sudo apt-get install -y libpcre2-8-0

to update to 10.39 solved this problem

Comment: for me this fixed the issue only when I restarted my already updated php 7.4.26 version

Comment: Indeed, a restart of the web server is necessary after the update ;)

Comment: In arch based systems you must upgrade "pcre2" package

Comment: I second this. On SLES 15 SP3 I upgrade from 10.31-150000.3.12.1 to  10.39-150400.4.9.1 (`zypper update libpcre2-8-0`, and to check available version details `zypper se  -s libpcre2-8-0`)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue, it is related to the latest patch PHP versions. It could be from this fix...
http://bugs.php.net/81424
PHP 8 changelog: https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.0.13