# This "preg_replace" not work for me in php 7.4

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, php-7.4

```
$regex = array(
                "`^([\t\s]+)`ism"=>'',
                "`^\/\*(.+?)\*\/`ism"=>"",
                "`([\n\A;]+)\/\*(.+?)\*\/`ism"=>"$1",
                "`([\n\A;\s]+)//(.+?)[\n\r]`ism"=>"$1\n",
                "`(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+`ism"=>"\n"
            );
$file_content = preg_replace(array_keys($regex), $regex, $file_content);
```

I received this warning:

> preg_replace(): Compilation failed: escape sequence is invalid in
> character class at offset 4

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `\A` inside square brackets.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764212/preg-match-compilation-failed-invalid-range-in-character-class-at-offset) is a good answer about the reason in general.

> PHP PCRE engine migrates to PCRE2

> PCRE2 is more strict in the pattern validations, so after the upgrade, some of your existing patterns could not compile anymore.

Comment: OK,
So what do I need put insted the - "\A" ?

Comment: I don't know what was your goal using \A in patterns. Looks like you can just remove it. Or move it outside of square brackets, like this `...(\A|[\n;]+...`