# Simple html DOM parser on Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, simple-html-dom

I have controller, which worked on Laravel 5.2 and used library  [yangqi/Htmldom](https://github.com/yangqi/Htmldom) (based on [simple HTML DOM parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)). Now I need to make the same logic on Laravel 8 and I can't find a library, which is based on **simple HTML dom parser** and working on Laravel 8 (yangqi/Htmldom - not working with Laravel 8).

I have all the need for logic based on simple HTML dom and I don't want to make it again with another library (for example Goutte).

Maybe someone can help me connect a simple HTML dom parser to Laravel 8?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You might want to clarify that you aren't seeking a library recommendation with this question, but trying to get existing functionality to work, as library recommendation questions are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed to next steps:

1. We need to change one part of code in package [yangqi/Html Dom](https://github.com/yangqi/Htmldom), instruction [here](https://github.com/yangqi/Htmldom/pull/27/files).
2. We need hyphen need to be escaped in all places like wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764212/preg-match-compilation-failed-invalid-range-in-character-class-at-offset).